# What should I use, "you're not going to tell me?" or "are you not going to tell me?"

Tags: grammar

"Are you not going to tell me?" or "You're not going to tell me?"

What should I use?

Comment: Both can be used to ask a question. When speaking though, in the case of the first example, make sure to use a rising intonation to indicate that what you are saying is actually a question.

Comment: @MichaelRybkin - That intonation would apply to both, not just the first one. (As a matter of fact, I'd say it's even more important in the latter than the former.)

Comment: The first one is grammatically correct, while the second one is not. However, you can use both in speaking. Just keep in mind that you 
 should use proper intonation so that people will understand what you are saying is a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of these are often used, and mostly **have the same meaning and are interchangeable**. However, there are circumstances where it makes a bit more sense to use either one.

Say you were trying to get your friend to tell you their favourite novel, for example, and they kept *indirectly* avoiding the question. This is a situation for **"Are you not going to tell me?"** because you are inquiring whether or not they will tell you; they have not already.

Alternatively, If your friend directly says, "I'm not going to tell you" or "I don't want to tell you" then saying **“you're not going to tell me?”** is most appropriate, because it is as if you are confirming what they've already said.

Even so, **either one is acceptable** in most situations, and English speakers do not always use them specifically to situations; they both sound natural in